# How do I get a PHP variable into JavaScript (p5.js) code?

Tags: javascript, php, p5.js

For a school project, I need to be able to switch between game modes within a game I am creating.

It's a simple snake game made with p5.js. But now I put the JavaScript files on a server and I need to be able to get a PHP variable and use it in a JavaScript variable, so I can distinguish the game modes from each other.

I've tried to use the PHP opening and closing syntax to write PHP in the JavaScript file. That didn't work.

After that I tried to write JavaScript in PHP, so I could create a variable with the contents of a PHP variable. That didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share a [mcve] showing these attempts? Thanks. Likely, you can do `<?php echo "<script>console.log($my_php_var);</script>";` but it's not necessarily appropriate for your scenario. Also, please elaborate on "didn't work"--was there an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php
    $bool = false;
    $num = 3 + 4;
    $str = "A string here";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // boolean outputs "" if false, "1" if true
    var bool = "<?php echo $bool ?>"; 

    // numeric value, both with and without quotes
    var num = <?php echo $num ?>; // 7
    var str_num = "<?php echo $num ?>"; // "7" (a string)

    var str = "<?php echo $str ?>"; // "A string here"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the Javascript in the `.php` file using the enclosing tags.

```php
<!--...--->
<script>
var a = <?=$a?>;
...
</script>
```

You can also JSON as well

```php
<!--...--->
<script>
var a = <?=json_encode([])?>;
...
</script>
```